# Get navigation height to become 100%

Tags: html, css

The navigation on the left is not going all the way down when the article section expands downwards. I want the navigation with the background color to expand downwards together with the article text to the right.

I have tried to add "height: 100%;" to the navigation column/box but it did not work.

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    /* Style the header */
    header {
      background-color: grey;
      padding: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 35px;
      color: white;
    }
    
    /* Create two columns/boxes that floats next to each other */
    nav {
      float: left;
      width: 30%;
      background: #ccc;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    /* Style the list inside the menu */
    nav ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    article {
      float: left;
      padding: 20px;
      width: 70%;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    /* Clear floats after the columns */
    section:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
    
    /* Style the footer */
    footer {
      background-color: #777;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
    
    /* Responsive layout - makes the two columns/boxes stack on top of             
    each other instead of next to each other, on small screens */
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
      nav, article {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>CSS Template</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2>CSS Layout Float</h2>
    <p>In this example, we have created a header, two columns/boxes and a     footer. On smaller screens, the columns will stack on top of each     other.</p>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect (you will     learn more about this in our next chapter - HTML Responsive.)</p>
    
    <header>
      <h2>Cities</h2>
    </header>
    
    <section>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      
      <article>
        <h1>London</h1>
        <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous     city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million     inhabitants.</p>
        <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by     the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
            <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most     populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13     million inhabitants.</p>
        <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by     the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
         <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most     populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13     million inhabitants.</p>
        <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by     the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
         <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most     populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13     million inhabitants.</p>
        <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by     the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
         <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most     populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13     million inhabitants.</p>
        <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by     the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
         <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most     populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13     million inhabitants.</p>
        <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by     the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
         <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most     populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13     million inhabitants.</p>
        <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by     the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
            <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most     populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13     million inhabitants.</p>
        <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by     the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
         <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most     populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13     million inhabitants.</p>
        <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by     the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
         <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most     populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13     million inhabitants.</p>
        <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by     the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
         <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most     populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13     million inhabitants.</p>
        <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
         <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
        <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
      </article>
    </section>
    
    <footer>
      <p>Footer</p>
    </footer>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

I expected "height: 100%;" to create the nav all the way down to the footer. But it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you want..

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Style the header */
header {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
}

/* Create two columns/boxes that floats next to each other */
nav {
  flex: 0 1 30%;
  width: 30%;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}
section{
     display: flex;
    justify-content: stretch;
}
/* Style the list inside the menu */
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  
}

article {
  flex: 0 1 70%;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
section:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Style the footer */
footer {
  background-color: #777;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns/boxes stack on top of             
each other instead of next to each other, on small screens */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  nav, article {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>CSS Layout Float</h2>
<p>In this example, we have created a header, two columns/boxes and a     footer. On smaller screens, the columns will stack on top of each     other.</p>
<p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect (you will     learn more about this in our next chapter - HTML Responsive.)</p>

<header>
  <h2>Cities</h2>
</header>

<section>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <article>
    <h1>London</h1>
    <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous     city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million     inhabitants.</p>
    <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by     the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
        <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most     populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13     million inhabitants.</p>
    <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by     the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
        <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most     populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13     million inhabitants.</p>
    <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by     the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
        <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most     populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13     million inhabitants.</p>
    <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by     the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
        <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most     populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13     million inhabitants.</p>
    <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by     the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
        <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most     populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13     million inhabitants.</p>
    <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by     the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
        <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most     populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13     million inhabitants.</p>
    <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by     the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
        <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most     populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13     million inhabitants.</p>
    <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by     the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
        <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most     populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13     million inhabitants.</p>
    <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by     the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
        <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most     populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13     million inhabitants.</p>
    <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by     the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
        <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most     populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13     million inhabitants.</p>
    <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major     settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
        <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
    <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
  </article>
</section>

<footer>
  <p>Footer</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: display: flex on section did the job indeed !

Comment: yeah right @RémyTesta. `display: flex` and `justify-content: stretch;` did it.

Comment: Okay. Yes, thats how I wanted it. Thank you Sbrrk. This is a nice CSS-template. Originally from W3schools.

Comment: @Methodius5510 if you get what you want then please upvote my answer. It will help me to grow.. thanks